# figure not in center in single column of double column template

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The problem is with this particular template, the image is not centred and also with the second code of three subplots, the label is showing two braces.

```
      \documentclass[twocolumn]{el-author}
    % \usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}

        \usepackage{cite}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
     % \usepackage{algorithmic}
   \usepackage{hyperref}


    \usepackage{diagbox}
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
       \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
     \usepackage{xcolor}
      \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfig}
     % \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

           \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

      % \usepackage{algorithmic}
     %\usepackage[...]{...}      This has been commented out as we are not using 
       any additional packages here.  On the whole, they should be unnecessary.
       \newcommand{\hH}{\hat{H}}
      \newcommand{\D}{^\dagger}
       \newcommand{\ua}{\uparrow}
      \newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
      \nc{\da}{\downarrow} \nc{\hc}{\hat{c}} \nc{\hS}{\hat{S}}
      \nc{\bra}{\langle} \nc{\ket}{\rangle} \nc{\eq}{equation (\ref}
      \nc{\h}{\hat} \nc{\hT}{\h{T}}\nc{\be}{\begin{eqnarray}}
   \nc{\ee}{\end{eqnarray}}\nc{\rd}{\textrm{d}}\nc{\e}{eqnarray}\nc{\hR} 
        {\hat{R}}\nc{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}}
     \nc{\tS}{\tilde{S}}\nc{\tr}{\mathrm{tr}}\nc{\8}{\infty}\nc{\lgs} 
    {\bra\ua,\phi|}\nc{\rgs}{|\ua,\phi\ket}
     \nc{\hU}{\hat{U}}\nc{\lfs}{\bra\phi|}\nc{\rfs}{|\phi\ket}\nc{\hZ} 
  {\hat{Z}}\nc{\hd}{\hat{d}}\nc{\mD}{\mathcal{D}}
   \nc{\bd}{\bar{d}}\nc{\bc}{\bar{c}}\nc{\mc}{\mathcal}\nc{\ea} 
     {eqnarray}\nc{\mG}{\mathcal{G}}\nc{\bce}{\begin{center}}
   \nc{\ece}{\end{center}}







     \begin{document}


       \begin{figure*}
     \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth,height=0.22\textwidth] {a.png}}
   \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth,height=0.22\textwidth] 
       {a.png}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth,height=0.22\textwidth] 
  {a.png}}
 \hfill
   \caption{ABCD}

      \vspace{-6mm}
   \end{figure*}


   \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    % \centerline{\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=9cm] 
  {pdf_plots/images21.pdf}}
     \centerline{\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=7cm]{a.png}}
      \caption{CABCDdddddddddddddd}
     \vspace{-4mm}
      \end{figure}










       \end{document}
```

Comment: Where did you get the `el-author` documentclass from? Also, do you get any error messages if you compile your document? If so, please do not look at the output. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: el-author is in the IET electronic letter template

Comment: Please provide link, where we can obtain it. I'm pretty sure, that journal provide an document example from where you can see, how to manage figures.

Comment: BTW, the \hfill will overwhelm \centering.  OTOH, that doesn't explain why how it got pushed into the margin.  What happens if you put \hrule into a figure*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The second image is wide then column width, consequently it protrude to the next column (or out of page border). Instead of say `width=10cm` as `includegraphics` options you should use for example `width=\linewidth` or `width=\columnwidth`.
- Don't use `\centerline{....}`. It is sufficient to use `\centering`.
- All `\vspace`, an other manual positioning commands in figure are superfluous.

**Edit:**

Meanwhile I install `el-author` document class. It seems that it is quite old. It load bunch of packages including:

- The (obsolete) `subfigure` package which is not compatible with `subfig` or `subcaption` (consequently in the first version of my answer had to be removed from preamble `\usepackage{subfig}` and in the `figure*` float replaced `\subfloat` with `subfigure`).
- The `url`, which not enable to load the `hyperref` package.
- for solving your problem definitions of new commands, showed in the `sample.tex` file are irrelevant to you your problem therefore I omitted them in my MWE below.

The MWE adopted to the `el-author` document class is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{el-author}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure*}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\linewidth,height=0.22\linewidth}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\hfill
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\hfill
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
\caption{ABCD}
\label{fig:aaa}
\end{figure*}

See Fig.~\ref{fig:aaa}. \lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7cm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{CABCDdddddddddddddd}
\label{fig:bbb}
\end{figure}

See Fig.~\ref{fig:bbb}. \lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: You need to invest more effort to prepare MWE (Minimal Working Example). Most of your document example is not related to your problem. Also you load some packages (for example `graphicx`) twice, etc. Important is formatting of your code. As example see my answer or answers on other questions.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved, Also  I can't change the format

Comment: Your comment gives no information what is wrong. What is the error? How the images are positioned? Which format you cant change? Clarify please.

Comment: @DiptiMishra, now a aded solution which works with `el-authoe`.

Comment: Thank you sir, the problem with fig:aaa is solved, but the problem with fig:bbb is still there, as my figure is shifted towards left in two column format, not in centre, as what u have shown

Comment: @DiptiMishra, if you test my answer as it is, than this cannot happen. You do something, what is hidden from us. Check, if your image has white space on its right side (insert it in `\fbox` for test).

Comment: ok yes, it was my mistake, the image itself has blank space in right, that's why its shifted towards left..thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: On more thing I want to ask, In the same el-author format, the caption of my table is not in centre, however, the table is centred, my table caption is left aligned.

Comment: @DiptiMishra, that is intentional by document class design. See the package documentation.

Comment: Is there something to fix it externally

Comment: @DiptiMishra, if you intend to publish in  *IET electronic letters*, than don't change their template design. I would rather focus my effort to article content. On the end they will retype your article anyway.